# How to get the referer url in symfony redirection

Tags: php, url, redirect, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 for some web application. In there when someone try to access one action I'm redirecting it to a new action as follows.

```
//Assume I'm redecting from module1/action1 to module2/action2
$this->redirect('module2/action2');
```

I in the module2/action2 can I get the url where it get redirected. I used

```
$request->getReferer();
```

But it doesn't give any result.

I don't need to use forward instead of redirect because it doesn't match for my need. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can suggest you to put the referer inside the session to be able to retrieve after your redirect. This how sfGuard [perform it](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/modules/sfGuardAuth/lib/BasesfGuardAuthActions.class.php#L54).

Before your redirect:

```
// save the referer
$referer = $this->getContext()->getActionStack()->getSize() > 1 ? $request->getUri() : $request->getReferer();
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('referer', $referer);

// make your redirect
$this->redirect('module2/action2');
```

Then, in your `module2/action2`, retrieve your referer like that:

```
$referer = $this->getUser()->getAttribute('referer');

// finally, remove it from session
$this->getUser()->getAttributeHolder()->remove('referer');
```

Comment: So where do we need to do this. Is it at a filter or somewhere.

Comment: Nope, you can put every thing in your action

Comment: Yes but then every action we have to put. It won't be a generic place where we can refer.

Comment: extend your controller by a custom one where yo put this